# Alternative to embed tag?

Tags: html, embed

I am trying to embed a PHP page in another HTML page using the embed tag, however on firefox it shows up as just a grey box. It works fine on google chrome. According to a google search, `<embed>` is deprecated and they suggest using the `<object>` tag however is it possible to use that with text/html and not an image or swf/media ?

My current code: `<embed src="post.php" height="35" width="850">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the following:

```
<object data=http://www.example.com/page.php width="850" height="35"> 
    <embed src=http://www.example.com/page.php width="850" height="35"> </embed>
    Error: The page could not be embedded.
</object>
```